# Azure Container Instances no internet access for Windows Container?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

My Windows Container in Azure Container Instances does not seem to be able to access the internet.

[image]

What can I do to access the internet from my Windows Container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to execute this PowerShell command in the container during startup:

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).IfIndex -ServerAddresses ('8.8.8.8')
```

Then my container was able to successfully resolve DNS and access the internet.

Executing this script in a RUN did not work, so I had to somehow execute it together with my already required CMD. I ended up doing it like this and it works:

```
CMD ["powershell", "-Command", "\"Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).IfIndex -ServerAddresses ('8.8.8.8')\"; cd c:\\app; .\\my.exe ui"]
```

Don't forget to escape `\` and `"`.